# Text Box with Tags in Jquery-jtable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-jtable

I want a textbox where i can enter tags as one of the fields in Jtable.
I am quite new to Jtable. I dont know whether it is possible or not.

Please refer the image in attachment.
ALso, I would also like to know how to store this multiple values data from tags textbox in database.

Thanks[image]